# OpenGL projection with gluProject()

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I am trying to get the Screen Coordinates of 8 corners of a cube.

Here is what I do:

```
int width = 640;
int height = 480;

GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble mvmatrix[16], projmatrix[16];

vector<GLdouble> testpoint_on_screen(24);
vector<GLdouble> vec(24);
```

Then in the draw function once I find the min and max 3D coordinates, I put them in an array and then copy this array to a vector as following:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    fMinX - scanSize, fMaxY + scanSize, fMaxZ + scanSize,
    fMaxX + scanSize, fMaxY + scanSize, fMaxZ + scanSize,
    fMaxX + scanSize, fMinY - scanSize, fMaxZ + scanSize,
    fMinX - scanSize, fMinY - scanSize, fMaxZ + scanSize,
    fMinX - scanSize, fMaxY + scanSize, fMinZ - scanSize,
    fMaxX + scanSize, fMaxY + scanSize, fMinZ - scanSize,
    fMaxX + scanSize, fMinY - scanSize, fMinZ - scanSize,
    fMinX - scanSize, fMinY - scanSize, fMinZ - scanSize
};

vector<GLdouble> convertionV(vertices, vertices + sizeof vertices / sizeof vertices[0]);

vec = convertionV;
```

And this is the display(), where I get the projection and model view matrices. Then I use gluProject() inorder to translate 3D to 2D.

```
void display()
{
    // clear the window
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // show the current camera frame

    //based on the way cv::Mat stores data, you need to flip it before displaying it
    cv::Mat tempimage;
    cv::flip(image, tempimage, 0);
    glDrawPixels( tempimage.size().width, tempimage.size().height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tempimage.ptr() );

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Here, set up new parameters to render a scene viewed from the camera.

    //set viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, tempimage.size().width, tempimage.size().height);

    //set projection matrix using intrinsic camera params
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float aspect = tempimage.size().width*1.0/tempimage.size().height;
    //gluPerspective is arbitrarily set, you will have to determine these values based
    //on the intrinsic camera parameters
    gluPerspective(60.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f); 

    //you will have to set modelview matrix using extrinsic camera params
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);  

    // get the viewport, modelView matrix and projection matrix
    glGetIntegerv (GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    glGetDoublev (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvmatrix);
    glGetDoublev (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);
    
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Drawing routine
    //initialise certain number of particles
    for(int i = 0; i<number_of_particles; i++){

        // uniformly distributed for the very first generation
        if((points[i].x == NULL) || (points[i].y = NULL)){
            //randomly generate X,Y,Z and angle values
            X_object = RandomNumber(-5.0, 5.0);//rand() % 10 - 2.5;
            Y_object = RandomNumber(-5.0, 5.0);//rand() % 10 - 2.5;
            Z_object = 23;
            cube_angle = 0;//rand() % 360 + 1;
        }else{
            //printf("second generation should improve the distribution");
            //set sigma accordingly
            //use best particle coordinates for the next X and Y            
            X_object = points[i].x;
            Y_object = points[i].y;
            Z_object = points[i].z;
            cube_angle = points[i].angle;
        }
      
        points[i].x = X_object;
        points[i].y = Y_object;
        points[i].z = Z_object;
        points[i].angle = cube_angle;



        gluProject(X_object, Y_object, Z_object, mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport, &point_on_screen[i].x, &point_on_screen[i].y, &point_on_screen[i].z);
    
        for(int opi = 0; opi < vec.size()/3; opi++){
            int currEl = opi * 3;
            gluProject(vec[currEl], vec[currEl + 1], vec[currEl + 2], mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport, 
                &testpoint_on_screen[currEl], &testpoint_on_screen[currEl + 1], &testpoint_on_screen[currEl + 2]);
        }

        glLoadIdentity();       
        glTranslatef(X_object, Y_object, -Z_object); //this is an arbitrary position for demonstration
        
        glRotatef(cube_angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Rotate about (1,1,1)-axis [NEW]
        DrawBox(4.0f, 3.5f, 5.0f, 5, 5, 5, 1.0, i);

    }

    // show the rendering on the screen
    glutSwapBuffers();

    // post the next redisplay
    glutPostRedisplay();

}
```

For some reason the first time I use gluProject with X_object, Y_object and Z_object (coordinates of front top left corner) it gives me correct values. However, while the second time I do it on all of the corners and it returns nonsense:

[image]

If someone can explain it to me or suggest a solution that'd be great.

Comment: Note that the OpenGL matrix functions as well as most of the GLU library are old and deprecated; you're better off using a library like GLM to do vector/matrix math (especially since you have to `glGet` the matrices from OpenGL, which may have performance implications).

Comment: I suggest you to read this bool http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Graphics-Using-OpenGL-Edition/dp/0131496700. For more graphics understanding.